# How to block Audio in Site specific permission on MS Edge browser?

Tags: microsoft-edge

How to set site specific settings for Audio on MS Edge browser? In Google Chrome, I can simply click on Paddle lock and turn off Audio. But on MS Edge I do not see these setting. I tried checking the Settings sections and searching for Audio settings. But there is none. I know one can click on tab and turn off Audio from there but that is not a permanent solution. I am looking for a permanent site specific setting for Audio and want to turn it off for specific website. As per my knowledge, MS Edge is Chromium based. But still not giving the same settings options like one see on Google Chrome. I wonder why. Any guidance or steps will be appreciated.

Comment: There's no such feature in Edge now. You can't turn off audio for specific website in Edge. I suggest that you can send feedback about this issue to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge. They'll look into it and improve Edge browser according to feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you can't mute specific sites, only tabs!

How to mute tabs in Microsoft Edge:

> 1.) Open Microsoft Edge, surf the web, and stumble upon a web-page you want to mute.

> 2.) Right click on the tab which has a speaker icon displayed, indicating audio output.

> 3.) Select “Mute Tab”, this then mutes all sound from the tab until you choose to unmute it.

> 4.) Alternatively, just click on the speaker icon to disable sound immediately.

I think that answered your question! :)

Answer (score 1):

edge://flags/

#edge-sound-content-setting

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/site-permissions-sound/m-p/743265

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Poroburu, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)